# Displaying the Address of Chars

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, char

So we have an assignment in my C++ class to create a pointer to a char and the instructions are:

For each declaration make sure to:

1. Initialize the pointer to an appropriate address value
2. Show the contents of the pointer (match this value with the address of what is pointing to)
3. Show the contents of what the pointer points to (match this value with the original contents)

Whenever I try to display the address of char a with &a , it just outputs the value stored in char a rather than the address. When I try this with integers it works like I want it to.

Can anybody give me an idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // Question 1, Part I

    // (a)
    char a = 'A';

    char * pa = &a;

    //(b)
    cout << "Address of a = " << &a << endl;
    cout << "Contents of pa = " << pa << endl;

    //(c)
    cout << "Contents of a = "<< a << endl;
    cout << "What pa points to = "<< *pa << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Edit & Run

Comment: Cast to a `void*`.  `cout` has special handling for `char*` which prints the string.  By the way, your code exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When you give a pointer to char to cout, it will consider it as a  null terminated c string.

Recast it to a void pointer:

```
cout << "Address of a = " << static_cast<void*>(&a)  << endl;
```

The standard guarantees that the adress is unchanged in section 4.10/2:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv T,” where T is an object type, can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv void”. The result of
>   converting a non-null pointer value of a pointer to object type to a
>   “pointer to cv void” represents the address of the same byte in memory
>   as the original pointer value.

Here an explanation about [pointer to char in output streams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/).  And here an explanation why [`void*` causes the value of the pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) to be displayed.

Answer (score -1):

Change these statements

```
cout << "Address of a = " << &a << endl;
cout << "Contents of pa = " << pa << endl;
```

to

```
cout << "Address of a = " << ( void * )&a << endl;
cout << "Contents of pa = " << ( void * )pa << endl;
```

or

```
cout << "Address of a = " << reinterpret_cast<void *>( &a ) << endl;
cout << "Contents of pa = " << reinterpret_cast<void *>( pa ) << endl;
```

or

```
cout << "Address of a = " << static_cast<void *>( &a ) << endl;
cout << "Contents of pa = " << static_cast<void *>( pa ) << endl;
```

All three variants will work.